# Why is my jquery-steps wizard giving a function not defined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I'm by no stretch of the imagination a web developer, so this is likely quite a basic issue.

I'm trying to copy the basic form from [an example](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) on the site. Here's my full `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="wizard">
  <section id="basic-form">
    <h2 class="page-header">Basic Form Example</h2>
      <form id="example-form" action="#">
          <h3>Account</h3>
          <section>
              <label for="userName">User name *</label>
              <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
              <label for="password">Password *</label>
              <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required">
              <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
              <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
              <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
          </section>
          <h3>Profile</h3>
          <section>
              <label for="name">First name *</label>
              <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required">
              <label for="surname">Last name *</label>
              <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
              <label for="email">Email *</label>
              <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
              <label for="address">Address</label>
              <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
              <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
          </section>
          <h3>Finish</h3>
          <section>
              <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
          </section>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
    var form = $("#example-form").show();

    form.validate({
      errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
        rules: {
                confirm: {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            }
        });


    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
        {
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            alert("Submitted!");
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this file, I get none of the nice bootstrap style and I get an error that `form.validate({ //...` is not a function.

I searched the `jquery.steps.min.js` for a `validate` method and, indeed, I could not find one.

Why doesn't this example work out of the box? Am I missing something from this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form validation is not a part of jQuery Steps. You've need to include "[jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)"

Comment: Ah, this fixed the immediate issue. I'm still not getting the expected wizard, but no more errors.

Comment: If you want the same styles you can grab them from github repository https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/master/demo/css/jquery.steps.css. Just save this file, and include to the page.

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much!

Comment: also you've an error in your jsfiddle example, form content should be wrapped in <div> or .children('div') should be removed.